# Unable to add list to the record

Tags: aerospike

I'm trying to add a record to the database having 3 bins, one of which is a list using my c++ program(I'm using Aerospike's C client library) but after I execute my program, only 2 of the bins are added in the record. For some reasons, I'm not able to add the 3rd bin having the list value.

Given below is the program:

```
#include<aerospike/aerospike.h>
#include<aerospike/as_arraylist.h>
#include <aerospike/as_record.h>
#include<aerospike/as_record_iterator.h>
#include <aerospike/as_policy.h>
#include<aerospike/aerospike_key.h>
#include<aerospike/as_std.h>
#include<aerospike/as_integer.h>
#include<aerospike/as_string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<aerospike/as_hashmap.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
        as_error err;
        as_config config;
        as_config_init(&config);
        config.policies.write.key = AS_POLICY_KEY_SEND;

        as_config_add_host(&config, "182.18.182.192", 3000);
        aerospike as;
        aerospike_init(&as, &config);

        if(aerospike_connect(&as, &err)!=AEROSPIKE_OK)
        {
                printf("error(%d) %s at [%s:%d]", err.code, err.message, err.file, err.line);
        }

        as_key key;
        as_record rec;
        as_record_init(&rec, 2);

        int n;
        cout<<endl<<"Enter the number of records to enter: ";
        cin>>n;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                cout<<endl<<"Enter the name: ";
                string pk;
                getline(cin>>ws,pk);

                as_key_init(&key, "test", "vishal_set", pk.c_str());

                cout<<endl<<"Enter the age: ";
                int age;
                cin>>age;

                as_record_set_int64(&rec, "age", age);

                cout<<endl<<"Enter the contact no: ";
                string contact_no;
                getline(cin>>ws,contact_no);
                as_record_set_str(&rec, "contact_no", contact_no.c_str());

                as_arraylist list;
                as_arraylist_inita(&list,2);

                as_arraylist_append_str (&list, "playing football");
                as_arraylist_append_str (&list, "playing cricket");

                cout<<endl<<"Number of elements in the list: "<<as_arraylist_size(&list)<<endl;

                if(!(as_record_set_list(&rec, "hobbies", (as_list *)&list)))
                {
                        printf("\n[%s::%d]Error\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
                }
                if (aerospike_key_put(&as, &err,NULL, &key, &rec) != AEROSPIKE_OK)
                {
                        printf("error(%d) %s at [%s:%d]", err.code, err.message, err.file, err.line);
                }

}
        if(aerospike_close(&as,&err)!=AEROSPIKE_OK)
        {
                printf("error(%d) %s at [%s:%d]", err.code, err.message, err.file, err.line);
        }
        aerospike_destroy(&as);


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, I've found the reason why my list was not getting added to the record myself. It turned out to be really silly mistake.

The reason was that I had done a mistake in initializing **`as_record`**. Since I was adding **3 bins** to the record therefore, I should have initialised it as **`as_record_init(&rec, 3);`**.